# Android: TabListener, unimplemented methods

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I have a class MyTabsListener inside my main activity as follows:

**Tabs Listener Class:**

```
class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public Fragment frag = new Fragment();

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.frag = fragment;
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Toast.makeText(JSONActivity.appContext, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag);
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(frag);
    }


}
```

I am using the support.v4 libraries when importing fragment, fragmenttransaction, etc..

However, eclipse tells me that:
*The type MyTabsListener must implement the inherited abstract method ActionBar.TabListener.onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab, FragmentTransaction)*

How can I fix this? If I change the class signature to:

`public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft)`

for example, then the method `ft.replace` or `ft.remove` will give me an error.

**My imports are:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This more than likely has to do with your imports. Make sure when you import something you always import the same version, whether its the support version or otherwise.

Comment: I seem to have all the support imports but I still get the error from eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can mix the support library (Fragment*) with the standard library (ActionBar*).  Google hasn't released the compatibility library for ActionBar as of yet so consider using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).